# Grails 3 and IntelliJ Unable to start project

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, grails3

Not even sure where to start at this point.  I've installed grails 3.2.4  I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2016.1.  I can create a new grails project using grails-3.2.4 and it appears to succeed, the Grails Console shows the create-app was successful.  The project creates and an IDEA window opens, but displays the message:

```
Gradle 'myProject' project refresh failed
    Error: Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I have no idea where this error comes from or how to specify a keystore.  If I go into the project directory (~/myProject) and attempt to run grails from the command line, it attempts to start before erroring out with:

```
 Error Error initializing classpath: Operation timed out
```

I tried adding proxy information to the gradle.properties file:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxy-server.company.com
systemProp.http.proxyPort=80
```

This seemingly has no effect.

The project in IntelliJ doesn't even seem to have grails support beyond the initial grails console output...  I cannot right-click to create new Grails objects on the project.  The "Tools" menu does not have a "Grails" sub-menu.  Run configurations do not allow me to select a grails project to run.  I'm at this point I'm just stabbing at things trying to get a new project created and running in grails 3.

**Update**: I got past the initial `unable to find certification path` error by downloading the gradle-version-bin.zip file and referencing it from the `gradle-wrapper.properties` locally instead of at the external distribution URL it tries to use out-of-the box.  This seems to allow it to try to update, but times out with the error

```
Operation timed out.  If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.
```

My IDE proxy settings are correct (Preferences --> Appearance --> System Settings --> HTTP Proxy) using an Automatic proxy configuration URL (as confirmed by running "Check Connection" from the preferences window).  Also tried adding the proxyHost to `gradle.properties` as I said above.  It seems that the update is not using the proxy, though.

**Update 2**: After getting gradle downloaded manually and installed locally, I eventually updated the maven repository URLs in `build.gradle` to use http instead of https.  Once I did this, I was able to refresh the project in the gradle window.  After this finished, the gradle view finally showed that there was a project and grails commands were available.

Not too savvy with certificates, but I think I should be able to download dependencies from secure repositories.

Answer (score 1):

After you created the project using **grails create-app name**, you need to import the project to intellij idea. Open IDE   go to **file->new->project from existing sources**. Then select the **build.gradle** file in your generated project. Click ok.

this will import the grails project into your IDE.

to run grails project,
right click on **grails-app/init/${projectName}/Application.groovy** and click on **run Application**.

you are good to go.

If IDE is not recognizing your grails then go to **tools -> grails -> change sdk version -> put the grails installation path there**.

Comment: I created the project using IntelliJ file -> new -> project...  so create-app was run inside IntelliJ.  The project is loaded in the IDE already, but does not appear to have finished creating.  There is no "Grails" under "tools" menu, that's part of the problem.

Comment: Trying to run the Application.groovy gives the error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: grails3test.Application

Comment: try to create project using grails create-app and import it like i said using build.gradle. Because intellij import the project as a gradle build project. and  every dependency is in build.gradle file even grails.

Comment: Whether I did create-app from command line or through IntelliJ, the result was the same...  the project never finished loading because it couldn't download gradle.  I'm updating the issue with how I got around the problem, but I'm not convinced I solved it correctly.